# Open desktop shortcut to SharePoint directly in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, shortcuts, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I have a desktop shortcut to a shared Excel spreadsheet that I use daily. It lives in a Microsoft Teams folder, i.e. on SharePoint. This shortcut opens a browser window asking me if I want to open the document in Excel.

Is there any way that I could skip this step, so that the shortcut just directly opens the file in Excel without bothering with the browser window?

(Bonus points if this could also open with write access straight away, rather than opening in read-only first!)

Comment: If a "shortcut" on your desktop includes app written in powershell or VBS (not VBA) then I think it's possible. The only issue would be write access, as that may depend on what rights you have to that file/directory. Good luck.

Comment: See what happens if you drag the sharepoint link directly onto the Excel icon. As for write access, try to add that doc as a trusted doc/source in Excel settings.

Comment: Did you create a desktop shortcut for the shared file **downloaded** to Microsoft Team folder from SharePoint? If yes, please right click it > Properties > General tab > make sure it is opened with Excel client.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible.

Workaround: You can open Office documents from Teams/SharePoint sites directly within the Office 2019 desktop apps using the "Sites" navigation item in the *File > Open* screen.

Alternatively, if you've already opened the file in question using the desktop app before, you can search for the name in the search box of the same screen and it will appear.

Neither of these solutions are as convenient as a Desktop shortcut, but they're a lot more convenient than having to use the awkward file browser in Microsoft Teams, especially if you're in a lot of teams, or the file you're looking for is nested several folders deep, or both (as was the case for me).

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible.

I created a desktop shortcut with this URL in it:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" https://[link to sharepoint file]
```

It is composed of the path to your Excel app installation folder, and the file's URL.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this in a very simple way.

In browser for Shairpoint, add Shortcut to OneDrive.

[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWveC.png)

On Desktop OneDrive folders, find file.

Right-click and add Shortuct to Desktop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).